# TypeScript nesting static properties

Tags: javascript, static, nested, typescript

I'm trying to build a class that will contain constant values to be used at different places.

The structure should be something like this:

```
class JavascriptEvents {
    static change: string = "change";
    static click: string = "click";
    static blur: string = "blur";
    static inputChange: string = "input propertychange paste";
    static dblClick: string = "dblclick";
    static bootstrap: Object = {
        accordion: {
            show: "show.bs.collapse",
            shown: "shown.bs.collapse",
            hide: "hide.bs.collapse",
            hidden: "hidden.bs.collapse"
        },
        modal: {
            shown: "shown.bs.modal",
            show: "show.bs.modal",
            hide: "hide.bs.modal",
            hidden: "hidden.bs.modal",
            loaded: "loaded.bs.modal"
        }
    }
}
```

Question: How should the `bootstrap` part be nested so I can reference an event like:

```
$("someElement").on(JavascriptEvents.bootstrap.modal.shown, function(){
    // do whatever needed
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `: Object` declaration, which hid all the type information from the call site. If you simply remove it, the type checker should be happy again.

E.g.:

```
class JavascriptEvents {
    static bootstrap: Object = {
        modal: {
            shown: "shown.bs.modal",
        }
    }
    static bootstrap2 = {
        modal: {
            shown: "shown.bs.modal",
        }
    }
}

let jq: any;
jq.on(JavascriptEvents.bootstrap.modal.shown); // Error
jq.on(JavascriptEvents.bootstrap2.modal.shown); // Works
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20JavascriptEvents%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20bootstrap%3A%20Object%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20modal%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shown%3A%20%22shown.bs.modal%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20bootstrap2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20modal%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shown%3A%20%22shown.bs.modal%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20jq%3A%20any%3B%0D%0Ajq.on%28JavascriptEvents.bootstrap.modal.shown%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0Ajq.on%28JavascriptEvents.bootstrap2.modal.shown%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Works)